# Python C API - Reload a module

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-c-api

I use Python 3.4 and Visual 2010.
I'm embedding Python using the C API to give the user some script capabilities in processing his data. I call python functions defined by the user from my C++ code. I call specific function like Apply() for example that the user has to define in a Python file.
Suppose the user has a file test.py where he has defined a function Apply() that process some data.
All I have to do is to import his module and get a "pointer" to his python function from the C++.

```
PySys_SetPath(file_info.absolutePath().toUtf8().data()));
m_module = PyImport_ImportModule(module_name.toUtf8().data());
if (m_module)
{
    m_apply_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(m_module, "Apply");
    m_main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(m_module);
}
```

So far, so good. But if the user modifies his script, the new version of his function is **never** taken into account. I have to reboot my program to make it work... I read somewhere that I need to reload the module and get new pointers on functions but the PyImport_ReloadModule returns NULL with "Import error".

```
// .... code ....
// Reload the module
m_module = PyImport_ReloadModule(m_module);
```

Any ideas ?
Best regards,
Poukill

Comment: The module most probably isn't loading. Can you add a PyErr_Print to see if there's an exception and which exception is it ?

Comment: I can't use PyErrorPrint since I'm using the Python C API. But with some inspection, I have a "Import can't find module, or can't find name in module." Which is weird because I just loaded the module at this very same place (PySys_SetPath has been used for that). If I use PyImport_ImportModule instead, it's working, I get a valid pointer, but not updated.

Comment: PyErr_Print is a c api function, an alias to PyErr_PrintEx. There are a few caveats around reloading and name resolution. Is there a possibility to just restart the interpreter ?

Comment: have you tried `importlib.reload(module)`? Calling `PyImport_ImportModule` the second time is pointless; it probably just returns the cached value from `sys.modules`. Make sure `PySys_SetPath`  argument contains *all* necessary paths (including pythonpath that is necessary for the user script).

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou : I know PyErr_Print is a C function, but it's printing directly into the python interpreter (sys.stderr) which I can not see. Like I said, I embed Python so I don't see the outputs of the interpreter for now, I have to capture the exception and the stacktrace using `PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback)`, but it's not that easy. Restarting the interpreter may be a option, but clearly not the best as I would have to stop any running session.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : The problem with `importlib.reload(module)` is that I don't get an updated m_module in my case, so my function pointers seem not to be updated. Maybe I really need to do this from C++ and not from Python ? Or maybe there is something wrong in my code, I will continue to dig into it.

Comment: @poukill: show the code. `importlib.reload()` is an ordinary Python function like any other. `module` is an ordinary object. Call the function, assign its return value to `m_module`. Function pointers  (and any other old references in your code) *won't* be updated automatically -- they continue to live until refcount is positive. You have to update all necessary references yourself.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : dude, you saved me. You were right, the `PySys_SetPath` has to contain the Python Path, then `PyImport_ReloadModule` returns a good value... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found in the comments of my first post (thank you J.F Sebastian), the `PySys_SetPath` has to contain also the PYTHONPATH. In my case, that is the reason why the `PyImport_ReloadModule` was failing.

```
QString sys_path = file_info.absolutePath() + ";" + "C:\\Python34\\Lib";
PySys_SetPath(UTF8ToWide(sys_path.toUtf8().data()));
m_module = PyImport_ReloadModule(m_module); // Ok !
```